# Combine Two Arrays into One array1=11,12,1 array2=am,pm,am to 11am, 12pm, 1am?

Tags: php, arrays

```
[time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

[ampm] => Array
        (
            [0] => AM
            [1] => PM
        )
```

I need this to output as 4am,5pm ... is this possible?

Comment: yes, it's possible. how? You write some code.

Comment: It's amazing that with over 70 array handling functions in PHP, none of them perform the classic functional "zip" operation.

Comment: I'm all in favour of answering questions but I'm kinda lazy at the moment: Why would you need an array like this? Ever looked at the datetime object and what you can output from it, especially paired with the timezone object?
If that doesn't help and the array combination feels difficult, why don't you declare the correct array straight away? array('12pm', '1am'...)? I don't get it.

Comment: Ha, it turns out that `array_map` can actually iterate through multiple arrays, passing an element of each array to the callback in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Time and ampm have to have the same amount of values)

```
<?php

    $array = array(
                "time" => array(4, 5),
                "ampm" => array("AM", "PM")
            );

    $output = array();

    for($count = 0; $count < count($array["time"]); $count++)
        $output[] = $array["time"][$count] . " " . $array["ampm"][$count];

    print_r($output);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 AM [1] => 5 PM )
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to display each array values in one row use this:

```
//print_r($output); delete this and write:

foreach($output as $value)
    echo $value . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
4 AM
5 PM
```

Comment: This worked for me here is what my code looks like: `<?php

    $array = array(
                "time" => $form->data['time'],
                "ampm" => $form->data['ampm']
            );

    $form->data['time'] = array();

    for($count = 0; $count < count($array["time"]); $count++)
        $form->data['time'][]= $array["time"][$count] . " " . $array["ampm"][$count];

    print_r($output);

?>`

Basically making a form to schedule interviews, so I can select 12/18/2015 and create the time slots available:)

Comment: in case im doing something wrong ;) I see the best answer wasn't what I used, but it still worked... now trying to figure out how to have them display in separate rows? Like 4AM on one row and 5PM on another?

Comment: @NateB updated my answer how you can display the values in separate rows, also you can do you're own answer if you figure it out yourself and you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to combine the elements of multiple arrays:

```
$newArray = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    return $a . strtolower($b);
}, $oldArray['time'], $oldArray['ampm']);
```

Comment: OP doesn't have multiple arrays! Or at least it doesn't seems like. If `timev and `ampm` would be 2 arrays he couldn't have keys from them. So use `$array["time"]`,...

Comment: @Rizier123 well, he does, they're just nested inside another array.  I'd already amended the code to reflect that when your comment arrived.

Comment: Nice ;D also you read the question very well you even have the `strtolower()`!!

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm not in the top 0.05% of users here for nothing, you know! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    'time' => ['4', '5', '11'],
    'ampm' => ['AM', 'PM', 'PM']
];

foreach ($myArray['time'] as $key => $time) {
    echo $time . $myArray['ampm'][$key];
}
```

this only works while $myArray['time'] and $myArray['ampm'] have a equal number of elements.

i'm not sure if i understood your question correctly. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply the "why" here yesterday but commented in the meantime that the purpose is to schedule interviews on a given date.
Whether limited by business hours or simply common sense, or indeed over a 24 hour span, you could create meaningful objects that can be displayed in any possible way rather than merging funny arrays.
Here is a simple example that includes your time zone, can be displayed in any possible way for output etc, it may get you started at least - please check the documentation, it is all there:

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-12-20 00:00:00');
$interval = 'PT1H'; ' 1 hour intervals

foreach (new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval($interval), 23) as $period) :
    var_dump($period);
endforeach;
```